# R making df longer, adding counts, percentages and total by group

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I want to make a data frame longer, add counts and percentages and then a total - all by group. Count and percentages I have but I need to add two rows of total. Reason is, that want a ggplot by facet_grid. Margins = TRUE doesn't work with geom_text.

This is the code for the longer df. It misses two rows with sums for am, like 'am 0 total' and 'am 1 total'.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)    

df_plot <- mtcars %>%
      group_by(am, vs) %>%
      summarise(cnt = n()) %>%
      mutate(freq = formattable::percent(cnt / sum(cnt), digits = 1))
```

Then it should be put in a plot with facet_grid

```
ggplot(df_plot, aes(x = as.factor(am), y = cnt, group=as.factor(am), fill = as.factor(am))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))+
  geom_text(label = with(df_plot, paste(cnt, paste0('\n(', freq, ')'))), vjust=-0.1, 
            position = position_dodge(width = .9))+
  facet_grid(cols = vars(vs), margins = F)
```

At the end there should be a third facet_grid with the total of 0 and 1. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to create a second df with the totals and bind it to the first dataframe:

Note: To add a character label for the totals and make the binding work I convert `vs` to a character.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df_plot <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(vs = as.character(vs)) %>%
  group_by(am, vs) %>%
  summarise(cnt = n()) %>%
  mutate(freq = formattable::percent(cnt / sum(cnt), digits = 1))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'am'. You can override using the `.groups`
#> argument.

df_plot <- df_plot |> 
  group_by(am) %>% 
  summarise(vs = "(all)", cnt = sum(cnt)) %>%
  mutate(freq = formattable::percent(cnt / sum(cnt), digits = 1)) %>%
  bind_rows(df_plot) %>%
  mutate(vs = factor(vs, c("0", "1", "(all)")))

ggplot(df_plot, aes(x = as.factor(am), y = cnt, group = as.factor(am), fill = as.factor(am))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(cnt, paste0("\n(", freq, ")"))),
    vjust = -0.1,
    position = position_dodge(width = .9)
  ) +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(vs))
```

[image]